# dbix::class generate schema for a non-catalyst app

Tags: perl, schema, catalyst, dbix-class

I've been building Catalyst apps lately and one thing I love is using Catalyst's create script to easily generate the table schemas for [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class). I'd like to be able to use DBIX::Class without having to write the schemas for my tables manually. Is there a way to do this without doing it by hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema%3a%3aLoader)'s `dbicdump` script can be used for dumping schema. An example from the documentation:

```
dbicdump -o dump_directory=./lib \
         -o components='["InflateColumn::DateTime"]' \
         -o debug=1 \
         My::Schema \
         'dbi:Pg:dbname=foo' \
         myuser \
         mypassword
```

Comment: Dumping a schema, or even user-defining a schema at all isn't strictly necessary. The following example demonstrates that D:C:S:L works the same as DBIC, trading just a little bit of start-up time: `perl -C -Maliased=DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader -e'Loader->naming("current"); my $d = Loader->connect("DBI:SQLite:foobar.db", undef, undef, { sqlite_unicode => 1 }); print $d->resultset("Foo")->first->quux'`

Answer (score 0):

The other, more generic module that supports that is [SQL::Translator](https://metacpan.org/release/SQL-Translator).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader 'make_schema_at';

my $DEBUG = @ARGV and $ARGV[0] =~ /^\-[\-]*v/;

say $DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::VERSION if $DEBUG;
my @dsn = 'dbi:Pg:dbname=yourDB.db';

my $options = {
debug          => $DEBUG,
dump_directory => 'lib',
components     => [qw/ InflateColumn::DateTime /],
generate_pod   => 0,
};

make_schema_at(Schema => $options, \@dsn);

=head1 NAME

generate_dbic_schema

=head1 USAGE

perl generate_dbic_schema

=cut
```